# Minecraft Windows 10 Edition - Invisible Interface

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft is having some problem. All home menu buttons do not appear, background keeps rotating but nothing appears.

I've reinstalled several times, both through the launcher and through the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of what is happening? It's not very clear what the issue is.

Comment: Did you have mods installed or edited any files or used other custom files from third parties on earlier installations?

Comment: I have had the same problem and I'm disappointed this very clear question has been closed when anyone who has ever played Minecraft can tell you exactly what is going on